# How can I take some user input (html or markdown), transform with XSLT, and write the resulting file to a library?

Tags: javascript, document-library, client-object-model, jquery, xslt

Not looking for a solution here, just something to get me started in the right direction.

I would like to create a page that takes some user input from a textbox (markdown would be cool, but HTML is fine too), transforms that input using XSLT, and writes a file to a document library. Ideally, I would like to accomplish this using the JavaScript CSOM.

What would this workflow look like? Is this just crazytalk?

Comment: I believe you'll need to write custom code for it. Write a webpart with a file upload control, read the file into memory, transform using XSL Tranformation classes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then write the memory stream to the document library.

Comment: Thanks! One thing: I don't want the user to upload a file; instead I want to allow the user to enter text on the page, then transform that text into some XML format.